# Delete an item by using this function but getting error

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

Structure of my arrData

[image]

I am using this function to delete an item from the database

### item.ts

```
 delete(i){
this.afDb.list('/FoodItems').remove(this.arrData[i].$key);}
```

while is the function that were i am using to retrieve

```
 afDb.list('/FoodItems').valueChanges().subscribe(_data => {
     this.arrData = _data;}
```

but I am getting an error:

> cannot read property of "$key" undefined

I am using many ways of trying to solve this problem...but can't.

Comment: Can you show your array data what structure is there in your `this.arrData` ?

Comment: @CodeChanger i have uploaded the structure image link above......please see above and try to solve my problem

Comment: @CodeChanger plz give me solution